# Finding Article Template for New Journal - PRX Quantum

Tags: publications, latex

I've undertaken some novel work as part of my undergraduate thesis and have been advised that this work goes sufficiently beyond the brief of an undergrad thesis and is novel enough to submit for publication. Since this will be my first paper and my supervisor is a subject matter expert, we've decided that we will coauthor an article based upon this research.

The most relevant fields are Quantum Electronics and Quantum Optics, so the logical place to publish this would seem to be Physical Review X's new spinoff PRX Quantum, launched last month.

However, I've been unable to find a LaTex template for articles in this new journal.

Would anyone know where I could find this? If not, would it be inappropriate to email the editor and ask if one exists?

Comment: Physical Review is normally very slow to update REVTeX.

Comment: There's not much difference between the different Physical Review styles, with the exception of PRL (no section headings, and if you use them in revtex no numbering), and special cases like RMP (and the now abandoned different citation style in PRB).  Any Phys Rev template in revtex, such as pra or prx, will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use the prx option included in [REVTeX-4.2](https://journals.aps.org/revtex), e.g. using
`\documentclass[prx,twocolumn,english,superscriptaddress,floatfix,longbibliography]{revtex4-2}` (Without having compared too closely, the style used by PRX Quantum seems to be the same as in PRX.) If you have an earlier version of REVTeX that doesn't support prx, just use the preset for another APS journal. Either way, they'll handle the minutiae of formatting should the manuscript be accepted.

It's not inappropriate to ask journal staff about templates, but [they state](https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/authors#submission) that submissions in REVTeX or MS Word are preferred, and I think using prx is the closest you can get using REVTeX at the moment.

Comment: Could you please point me to a resource that explains how to use PRX with REVTeX (bonus points if it has a template) or is it just a document class? I did see the REVTeX page and got the impression it was just a set of macros?

Comment: @Persistence Here's what I have in a manuscript in preparation for PRX: \documentclass[prx,twocolumn,english,superscriptaddress,floatfix,longbibliography]{revtex4-2} That's pretty much it. The 'longbibliography' option prints titles of the cited references.

Comment: Thanks my dude!

Answer (score 1):

The [*Information for Authors*](https://journals.aps.org/prxquantum/authors) page of PRX quantum links to the [*Physical Review Style and Notation Guide*](https://cdn.journals.aps.org/files/styleguide-pr.pdf), which is common to all APS journals.

You can see from that guide that it recommends the usage of [REVTeX](https://journals.aps.org/revtex) for the preparation of the manuscript.